# Database Cleaner mongomapper and cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongomapper

```
#/features/support/env.rb
...
require 'database_cleaner'
require 'database_cleaner/cucumber'
require 'database_cleaner/mongo_mapper/truncation'
DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation

Before do
  DatabaseCleaner.start
end

After do
  DatabaseCleaner.clean
end
```

Result

```
Exception encountered by DatabaseCleaner in Cucumber After block: ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished
```

If I comment Before and After block - tests work fine without DatabaseCleaner

ree-1.8.7-2011.03
rails (2.3.12)
mongo_mapper (0.7.5)
cucumber (0.8.7)
cucumber-rails (0.3.2)
database_cleaner (0.6.7)

Answer (score 0):

looks like it's still using ActiveRecord, try disabling it